# How to change one array element by index, without changing the same element in a duplicated array? (python, numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, clone

This is the code I have an issue with:

```
R = np.ones(16) * -100
for i in np.arange(10):
    print('Range of 100: ', i , ' Repetitions finished')
    R_save = R
    print(R_save)
    R[0] = 3
    print(R)
    print(R_save)
    comparison = R == R_save
    if comparison.all():
        print('finished Range of 100 potences')
        print(R)
        print(R_save)
        break
```

The idea is to change the first entry of the R-array in the first repetition while keeping the R_save-array the same. In the second repetition the if condition should be TRUE and stop the loop.
However the R_save entry changes along with the R entry. If someone could help me understand how to get around this issue or better understand it I would much appreciate it :)
Thank you so much!
Alex

Comment: `R_save = R.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

`R` and `R_save` are two variables pointing to the same array, so you cannot "change only one" - there **is** only one array, with two variables referencing it.

Instead, you can copy `R` when you create `R_save`, so there really are two different arrays with (initially) the same elements:

```py
R_save = np.copy(R)
```